# Extract and combine data from 3 large tsv/csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, vaex

I have 3 big tsv files with the following structure :

```
 file1 : id,f1,f2,name,f3
 file2 : id,f4,blah1,f5
 file3 : id,f5,f6,blah2
```

I want to create a third file that is extract from the others:

```
 result: id,name,blah1,blah2
```

Currently i cant because just trying to load one of the files in panda|vaex crashes the process, because it tries to read the whole file..

How to do that.. ?

I will use the resulting file in vaex ... it will still be ~1G i think

---

```
f1 = vaex.read_csv('stuff.tsv',convert=True,sep='\t')
```

and then :

```
f1.join(f2,left_on='id',right_on='id')
```

Comment: in the `read_csv` method, you can specify which column to load, so you could do `pd.read_csv(file1, usecols=['id','name'])` idem for the others. that would decrease the size of the loaded data

Answer (score 1):

'convert' does not load the file in memory ...but works in chunks

```
f1 = vaex.read_csv('stuff.tsv',convert=True,sep='\t') 
f2 = vaex.read_csv('stuff2.tsv',convert=True,sep='\t') 

fx1 = f1['id','blah1']
fx2 = f2['id','blah2']
```

and then :

```
ff = fx1.join(fx2,left_on='id',right_on='id')
ff.export_hdf5('file.hdf5')
```

Answer (score 0):

A strategy like this one might make your work easier. It tracks the `merged_items` dict that tracks items by `id`, and holds the values for `name`, `blah1` and `blah2`. Then, using `csv`'s `reader`, it iterates each file, line by line, instead of all-at-once, to reduce necessary memory used at any one time. At the end, it writes out items row-by-row again. You'll need to tinker with this to fit your exact use-case, but it should be a decent start.

```
merged_items = {}

with open ('file1.csv','r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader) # skip first row
    for row in reader:
        row_id = row[0]
        name = row[3]
        merged_items[row_id] = {'name':name}


with open ('file2.csv','r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader) # skip first row
    for row in reader:
        row_id = row[0]
        blah1 = row[2]
        merged_items[row_id]['blah1'] = blah1


with open ('file3.csv','r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader) # skip first row
    for row in reader:
        row_id = row[0]
        blah2 = row[3]
        merged_items[row_id]['blah2'] = blah2

with open('output.csv','w', newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='\t') # change these options as you see fit
    for id, metadata in merged_items.items():
        writer.writerow([id, metadata['name'], metadata['blah1'], metadata['blah2'])
```